# How do I figure out property cardinality in vCard 2.1 and 3.0

Tags: webdav, vcf-vcard, carddav

In vCard 4.0 specification each property has cardinality specified in [RFC 6350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-3.3)

How do I find out cardinality for vCard 2.1 and 3.0? Are there any sign what the property with the same name can be included more than once in vCard 2.1 and 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official mailing list:

> On 2012-05-14 10:13, Andrew Pace wrote:
>
> > Is there a
> >     list of properties with cardinality for Vcard3.0, like it is shown in
> >     RFC6350?
>
> No, it does not exist. That's one of the many "bugs" in vCard 3.0 that 
>   were fixed in 4.0.
>
> Simon

Reference: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.ietf.vcarddav/313